# HTACCESS Redirect Username

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am building a social network and having an issue with the profile url's put simply I am trying to change up the the messy url from...

```
www.mysite.com/user.php?u=MyUsername
```

to

```
www.mysite.com/user/MyUsername
```

Simple enough I thought with just htaccess so I added this to it...

```
RewriteRule ^user/([0-9a-zA-Z]+) user.php?u=$1 [NC,L]
```

but it seems it does not work on my system everytime I navigate to /user/MyUsername it redirects to....

```
www.mysite.com/user/MyUsername/u?=MyUsername
```

I was asked to put the entire htaccess file in here so here goes...

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^tmysite\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ mysite.com/$1 [R=permanent,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /(([^/]+/)*)index\.(html?|php[45]?|[aj]spx?)\ HTTP/
RewriteRule index\.(html?|php[45]?|[aj]spx?)$ mysite.com/%1 [R=301,L]

#Rewrite for signup.php login.php logout.php
RewriteRule ^login login.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^signup signup.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^logout logout.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^UserGuide user_guide.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^forgotpass forgot_pass.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^user/([0-9a-zA-Z]+) user.php?u=$1 [NC,L]

ErrorDocument 404 /pagenotfound.php
ErrorDocument 403 /403.php

<Files 403.shtml>
order allow,deny
allow from all
</Files>
```

Just to let you know all of the other RewriteRules work perfectly.

Comment: Put the entire contents of htaccess file here.

Comment: Sure ill update the question for you @hjpotter92

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Tested code:**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^u=(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^user.php /user/%1? [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^user/([0-9a-zA-Z]+) user.php?u=$1 [NC,L]
```

**Explanation:**

- `%{QUERY_STRING} ^u=(.+)$` will catch the GET variable `u`. Everything that variable contains is passed to `%1`. Also, the `R=301` will redirect with SEO friendly 301 header code. Notice that if you want to use multiple GET variables in the url, you will have to change the syntax a little.
- The last rule RewriteRule `^user/([0-9a-zA-Z]+) user.php?u=$1 [NC,L]` will catch that url of yours `www.mysite.com/user/MyUsername` to `user.php?u=$1`.

Answer (score 0):

To redirect a username as follows:
[www.aeonlabs.solutions/@mtpsilva](http://www.aeonlabs.solutions/@mtpsilva)

to redirect to
[www.aeonlabs.solutions/curriculum/mtpsilva](http://www.aeonlabs.solutions/curriculum/mtpsilva)

one can setup .htaccess like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} @(.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*) /curriculum/%1/? [L,R=301]
```